# Horrible AO Texture Bake

Tags: mesh, materials, uv, node-editor, image

I am trying to bake the AO from a high poly model to a low poly one, however I keep getting a horrible looking texture, I have tried deleting other meshes that may be overlapping with the models but it still seems to be happening (My model is UV unwrapped properly).

I have also tried baking from AO directly and also plugging an AO node into diffuse and trying to bake that.

[image: High Poly Model Next to Horrible Texture]

[image: Low Poly Model with Horrible Texture Applied]

The Steps I have followed are:
1) Turn on ambient occlusion in the world tab.
[image: AO World Setting]

2) Hook up an ambient occlusion node to the diffuse of high poly material
[image: High Poly Node Setup]

3) Create blank texture map
4) Select the High Res, then Low Res.
5) Select newly created texture.
6) Then Select 'Bake'
[image: Bake Settings]

Is there something that I am missing, I did a similar process for my normal and cavity maps and it worked fine.

[image: Cavity Map Came Out Fine]

I am really struggling with this and would appreciate any ideas as to what I could do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out my issue was with some hidden geometry (the original sculpt).
The AO map came out looking as expected after this was hidden from the renderer. 
[image: Problem Geometry Hidden in Render]
[image: AO Map Came Out as Expected]

Sorry if anyone was in the process of answering.

Comment: you should probably mark your answer as accepted, just to "close the case".